# LINQ get the count

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following query which is returning the expected result but I'm having trouble accessing the Tickets count:

```
home.Projects = _db.Projects.Where(p => p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userid)).Include(t => t.Tickets).ToList();
```

Comment: `home.Projects[0].Tickets.Count;` (or `Count()` if Tickets if `IEnumerable<T>` to get the count of tickets for the first project.

Comment: Projects is an ICollection so I can't apply indexing to it. I'm guessing I could loop through but looking for a faster/easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SelectMany:

```
home.Projects.SelectMany(i => i.Tickets).Count();
```

SelectMany compresses the one to many result into a singular result for this very purpose.